# Session between webpart e Aspx - Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Session between webpart e Aspx - Sharepoint 2007
I trying to transfer some information in Session, but using Responde.Redirect doesn't work.
When I use Server.Transfer(url) needs to go to /site-test/_layouts/teste.aspx, but just works when I use Server.Transfer with _layouts/teste.aspx

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Eduardo, could you revise your question? It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to do - very possibly using sessions is the wrong (or certainly not the only way) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect do not work in SharePoint, You should use [SPUtility.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect.aspx) instead. Furthermore, sessions are not enabled in SHarePoint by default (only in multiserver farms I think). You have to enable it in Central Admin. See [this post](http://vspug.com/erickraus/2007/12/09/enable-session-state-in-sharepoint-2007/) on how to do that.

Be aware sessions can be a tricky thing when your front-ends are behind a load-balancer, when that is not set to sticky sessions, postbacks could fail.

Another thing, if you want webparts to communicate, there is a mechanism in place just for that, Sahil Malik covers the basics (ASP.NET) [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/05/14/aspnet-20-webpart-communication-the-preface-to-sharepoint-2007-webpart-communication.aspx), and how it is done in Sharepoint [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-7-Sharepoint_Webparts_AS_-_Connecting_the_WebParts_-_making_an_RSS_Reader_Application.aspx). For more info, google for [sharepoint webpart communication](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=sharepoint+webpart+communication).

Comment: Colin, 
Thank you for your answer...
Problem solved.
I used SPPersistedChildCollection to cache.